# Print indexed array value in view.blade.php in laravel5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have one associative array $collection and one indexed array $gnd which I have passed from Controller to my view.blade.php in Laravel 5.2. I want to print the values of both the arrays in a single table. Here is my code,

```
<table class="responsive-table highlight centered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">Sl.no</th>
            <th data-field="name">Unique </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th data-field="price">Description</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

   <tbody>
       {{-- */$j = 1;/* --}}
        @foreach($collection as $key=>$value)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $j }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->uid }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->desc }}</td>
                <td>{{ $gnd[$j] }}</td>
                {{-- */$j++;/* --}} 
                @endforeach 
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For {{ $gnd[$j] }} I am getting the following error.

```
ErrorException in b7c1ab515a44988c31e1982a3ce014434e97ef2c.php line 30:
Undefined offset: 22 (View: /var/www/html/anudip/resources/views/plugins/entries/view.blade.php)
```

I am new in laravel. Please help me...

Function that passes the two arrays from Controller:

```
public function getDetails(){
    $collection = DB::table('entry_transactions')
                  ->leftJoin('entry_masters', 'entry_transactions.entry_id', '=', 'entry_masters.id')
                  ->get(['entry_masters.id as uid','entry_masters.name as name','entry_masters.gender as gender','entry_transactions.entry_desc as desc']);

$gnd = array(); 
$len = sizeof($gnd);
$i = 0;

foreach ($collection as $key) {

    if($key->gender == 0){
        $gnd[$i] = "Male";
    }   
    else {
        $gnd[$i] = "Female";
    }
    $i++;
}

    return view($this->url.'entries.view', compact('collection','gnd'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting because both array's size are not equal!

And why are you starting `$j = 1`? shouldn't be `$j = 0`, if both your arrays has the same size `$j = 0` will fix your problem and change `<td>{{ $j }}</td>` to `<td>{{ $j+1 }}</td>`

Also, can you show us your controller function that is sending this two arrays?

Comment: Thanks theMohammadA. It worked. I am showing my controller that passes the two arrays. Thanks once again...